# TypeScript: Inferring function arguments from a constructor signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

As a tool for composability, I have a function that takes a class constructor argument and returns a function that uses the arguments it is passed to construct an instance of the class I initially passed in.

```
class Thing {
  constructor (metadata) { this.metadata = metadata; }
}

const A = (C) => (...a) => new C(...a);
const X = A(Thing);
```

When I hover over `X`, I want it to tell me that the function signature is essentially `(metadata) => Thing`. Instead, it says that the signature of `X` is `(...a) => any`. What annotations are required in order to get TypeScript (latest version) to infer the signature of X correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const A = <T extends unknown[], K>(C: new (...args: T) => K) => (...args: T) => new C(...args);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqAWBLAdgc2gbwFDV9AtgKYAuYAJmKQFzTICu+ARoQE4DcWOewA9shMRZ1gxHi2gAKIqQrVaDZiwCUmaMSQQAdNPKUw0ALwESu0m2gBfLFay9+xaAEFD0ADyxohAB7FCyMjB0yADWyDwA7sgA2gC6ADTQANIAfBIAwjTIhOGSmnlgLKgQNLAqBslJZRUSeZoFRSVVtNnQaTX5hRBKHHYC0AAaLo4SCCio3VhAA)

Breaking it down, we have a `T` array type, and we annotate `C` to have a constructor (using the `new` keyword) that takes in the args denoted by `T`, and returns a value `K`. We then return a function that essentially undoes the constructor.

As a side note, please compile with `--noImplicitAny`; it'll give you helpful warnings for things like this where arguments have an `any` type due to not specifying their type.